# ES6 how to use object destructuring without assigning variables

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, destructuring, object-destructuring

Maybe a luxury problem, but Im searching for the most elegant way to pass a selection of object parameters to a function. This is what I'd like to achieve :

```
const allParameters = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
    c: '3',
    private_d: '4',
}
function executeWithHiddenParameters(callback){
    return callback( {a,b,c} = allParameters );
}
```

Currently Im using this kind of solutions:

```
function executeWithHiddenParameters(callback){
    const {a,b,c} = allParameters
    return callback( {a,b,c} );
}
```

somehow to me it seems a bit cumbersome to initialize the parameters and then create a new object. I suppose when used in large scale this could also be relevant for performance issues?

So my question actually is about object descructuring:
What does the destrucuring operator actually return? What is happening under the hood? How can it be used as simple oneliner?
(literature and links also very much appreciated :D )

Comment: Destructuring creates a bunch of consts / variables, that's all. What you can do here is either `callback(allParameters)` or `callback({ ...allParameters })` I get that you're deliberately not passing `private_d` however if you don't want to do that, your second method is the only possible way (I know of).

Comment: *"somehow to me it seems a bit cumbersome to initialize the parameters and then create a new object."* You will have to create a new object if you want to pass only some properties and not mutate the original object. If you can mutate the original object, then all you have to do is `delete allParameters.private_d`. *"What does the destrucuring operator actually return?"* It's not an operator. The operator is the *assignment operator* but instead of assigning to a single variable you are assigning to multiple ones. Based on the syntax, the JS engine knows whether to access object or iterator.

Comment: It seems like you are asking for special syntax to create a new object while excluding some properties. There is no syntax for that but you could write a helper function that does that for you (and this questions has also been asked on Stack Overflow before).